# Commandline tools to restore a versioned deleted file in S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, data-protection, s3cmd, cloudberry

I have versioning enabled in my S3 bucket, how do I restore a deleted file with a command line S3 client, such as [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd)? How do I browse the different versions of the files? So far, I have regressed to [Freeware Cloudberry Windows Client](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/how-to-manage-amazon-s3-versioning-with-cloudberry-explorer/) to achieve this. I know I could use also [Boto Python library](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), but I would prefer a common command line tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this AWS CLI command: ([docs here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-object-versions.html)):

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket mybucket
```

This returns the list of objects, eg.:

```
{
    "DeleteMarkers": [
        ...
    ],
    "Versions": [
        {
            "LastModified": "2015-11-17T12:25:01.000Z",
            "VersionId": "Mj1.PcWG8e.C._7LhvFU131pXJ98abIl",
            "ETag": "\"b76b2b775023e60be16bc332496f8409\"",
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "Key": "file1.txt",
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "aws03005",
                "ID": "b09   0e41acbdf98bc34ef4781f10e4aeebb7a495b8be78da0db884af2980ed38d"
            },
            "IsLatest": true,
            "Size": 30318
        },
    ...
}
```

Use `Key` (file name) and `VersionId` to download a previous version:

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket mybucket --key file1.txt --version-id Mj1.PcWG8e.C._7LhvFU131pXJ98abIl foo.txt
```

If you are trying to get a deleted file, please note that you have to `get-object` the latest version listed in `Versions`, **not** the one listed in `DeleteMarkers`.

To do this in a script, `--query` and/or [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) might help.

Comment: You are right, better approach is to use the [official tool developed by Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/). The development of [s3cmd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/s3tools/files/s3cmd/) seems to have dried up anyway.

Answer (score 2):

s3cmd 1.5.0-rc1 has very little support for versioned files at this point.  I believe it can do a full bucket delete, including versioned files, but that's the extent of its support for versioned files.

Comment: I believe you are referring to this pull request https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/pull/345